# What is the public whois server for .IN.NET domain names?

Tags: domain-name, whois

If I am going to be performing a Whois lookup for a domain name with the extension `.IN.NET`, which whois server should I connect to?

For example, for `.com` domain names, I would format my whois query as follows:

```
whois -h whois.verisign-grs.com example.com
```

What is the equivalent for `.IN.NET` domain names? I am interested in what to put as the server (`<?>`).

```
whois -h <?> example.in.net
```

Answer (score 4):

`.IN.NET` is a second level domain name psuedo-registry operated by [CentralNic](https://www.centralnic.com/portfolio/slds).

The whois server for CentralNic domain names is `whois.centralnic.com`.

In the case of psuedo-registries, [IANA](http://www.iana.org/) does not manage any data about these extensions because they are not assigned by ICANN. For the most part, you would already have had to known that CentralNic manages `.IN.NET` or checked the DNS records for `_nicname._tcp.in.net`, which is a loosely followed standard -- it will not always give you results.

So, in your case, you will use the `whois` command as follows:

```
whois -h whois.centralnic.com example.in.net
```

If this was a normal extension (e.g. `.COM` or `.NET`), then you can find out the whois server by querying IANA's whois server.

Example:

```
whois -h whois.iana.org com

.
.
.

whois:        whois.verisign-grs.com

status:       ACTIVE
remarks:      Registration information: http://www.verisign-grs.com

created:      1985-01-01
changed:      2012-02-15
source:       IANA
```